# How to use Luxon with Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs, luxon

I was looking for a library to use with Angular2 to handle dates and make diff/add, translations, etc ...
I tried to install **Luxon** (http://moment.github.io/luxon/) by installing it via 
`npm install --save-dev @types/luxon` but it fails.

I always have errors like below when I compile my code:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'luxon' in 'D:\App\src\app\planning-team'
>   resolve 'luxon' in 'D:\App\src\app\planning-team'
>     Parsed request is a module
>     using description file: D:\App\package.json (relative path: ./src/app/planning-team)
>       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

Does anyone already use Luxon with Angular ?
How do you do ?

Thanks for your help.
Regards,
Mike

Comment: You've only installed the TypeScript typings. But not the library itself: `npm install --save luxon`. https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/install.html

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet it's working fine now using import { DateTime} from 'luxon';

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
npm i luxon

npm i @types/luxon -D
```

Then your import:

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';
```

Now you can call `const now = DateTime.local()` in your Typescript.

Comment: and what happens if I don't want to include luxon in my main bundle instead of loading it from a CDN?